# Making a GeoJSON layer editable with the Leaflet.Editable plugin

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm new to Leaflet and the Leaflet.Editable plugin, but I'd like to make GeoJSON layer editable. When I mean "editable", I mean a user can stretch the polygons at will.

[Here](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.Editable/example/index.html) is a good example of what I'd like.

My current code is as follows:

```
var map = L.map('mapid', {editable: true}).setView([39.08344, -77.6497145], 13);

L.tileLayer('Some Valid Tile Layer',
    {
    attribution: 'Myself',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

$.ajax({

    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/map/geoJSON/elementary_boundaries.geojson',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

        console.log('The data was received');
        L.geoJson(data, {

            onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                layer.enableEdit(); // incorrect, but code would go here

            }
        }).addTo(map);

    },

    failure: function(data){
        console.log('The data wasn\'t received');
    }

});
```

I don't fully understand features vs layers, and I fully don't understand leaflet's geometry construction flow, so I'm sure my problem is elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem, though I'm not sure if my solution is the most "ideal" way.

I'm going to give some insight into what I learned and some of this may be wrong, so please let me know so this post can be as accurate as possible.

The Leaflet.Editable plugin only works consistently with Leaflet Vector Layers. These are the classes of Polyline, Polygon, Rectangle, Circle, and Marker. When you use L.GeoJSON, you're creating a different kind of Layer.

The solution is to read the GeoJSON file and instead of making a GeoJSON layer, make a Layer of the Vector variety.

The GeoJSON I used had a type of FeatureCollection. So parse the file and covert each feature into a Polygon class. The code is below

```
var map = L.map('mapid', {editable: true}).setView([39.08344, -77.6497145], 13);

L.tileLayer('A Valid Tile Layer',
    {
    attribution: 'Myself',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

$.ajax({

    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/map/geoJSON/elementary_boundaries.geojson',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

        var latLong = [];
        var thisTime = true;
        data.features.forEach(function(currentFeature){

            currentFeature.geometry.coordinates[0].forEach(function(locationArray){

                locationArray.forEach(function(location){

                    latLong.push([location[1] , location[0]]);
                });
            });

            var polygon = L.polygon(latLong).addTo(map);
            polygon.enableEdit();
            latLong = [];
        });
    },

    failure: function(data){
        console.log('The data wasn\'t received');
    }

});
```

The following part is necessary because GeoJSON specification requires that coordinates to be in [longitude, latitude] and Leaflet (or OpenStreetMap, can't remember) requires [latitude, and longitude]

```
    currentFeature.geometry.coordinates[0].forEach(function(locationArray){

        locationArray.forEach(function(location){

            latLong.push([location[1] , location[0]]);
        });
    });
```

I had a GeoJSON file of over 250,000 lines, so maybe the plugin works differently for large files, but this solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

For future searchers, an alternative solution is to catch the 'edited' event from the editable extension and update the GeoJSON geometry to match that of the layer:

```
 this.mapHost.map.on('editable:vertex:dragend', (event: any) =>
      {
         // Note: the layer latlngs have been updated here but not the geojson geometry
         // copy changes to geojson
         event.layer.feature.geometry = (event.layer as any).toGeoJSON().geometry;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your success callback from the `$.ajax` call:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log('The data was received');
    var layer = L.GeoJSON.geometryToLayer(data);
    layer.addTo(map);
    layer.enableEdit();
}
```

Comment: That's for responding, but when I tried your code it didn't work. I got the following error: Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.

Comment: not sure, it worked for me with this: `{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Bermuda Triangle",
    "area": 1150180
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [-64.73, 32.31],
        [-80.19, 25.76],
        [-66.09, 18.43],
        [-64.73, 32.31]
      ]
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: can you `console.log` your data, and then check that it is valid using [GeoJSON lint](http://geojsonlint.com/)

Comment: also you might find some of the discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/187) helpful. Different Leaflet plugin, but same issue

Comment: My GeoJSON file is about 3 MB and it isn't formatted "nicely". Most validators I find reject it for its size. The link you sent me gave me three outputs: Line 2: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule, Line 2: a LinearRing of coordinates needs to have four or more positions, Line 2: old-style crs member is not recommended, this object is equivalent to the default and should be removed. 

I believe these are irrelevant. The GeoJSON file renders correct and looks like expected, so I know the file is correct.

Comment: I've also looked at the discussion you've sent me and I've downloaded Leaflet.Draw in hopes of solving my problem.