# Pushing features to external GeoJSON file

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, leaflet-draw, ajax

I am working on a project which uses Leaflet and leaflet.draw to show and draw shapes on the map. I also have a data.json file which I use to display former features generated from geojson.io. What I want to do is, after I finish drawing a feature I want it to be saved in the data.json file. I am trying to do this by getting the newly created feature by leaflet draw and pushing it to the feature collection object in the json file. I am not quite understanding how I am supposed to do that. create a new object, how do I get the coordinates and the feature type inte the javascript object.

This is the code I use to get the features from the JSON file.

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.15.79:8080/PathTO/data.json", function(data){
  L.geoJson(data,{
    style: featureStyles
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

And this is what I have tried so far

```
  var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawPluginOptions);
  map.addControl(drawControl)
  var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
  map.addLayer(editableLayers)
  map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
    var type = e.layerType;
    var layer = e.layer;
    var newFeature = { 
      "type": "features", 
      "geometry": { 
        "type": layer.type,
        "coordinates": layer.getLatLngs()
      //to be continued...
      } 
    };   
    editableLayers.addLayer(e.layer);



   //editableLayers.push(layer);
   // editableLayers.layers.push(serverResponse.featuresOnWs);
  });
```

Comment: Almost duplicate of this.https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316407/push-attributes-to-geojson-in-leaflet?noredirect=1#comment514671_316407  However your looking at creating a array of current features, push the new ones, and over write the existing file, which is only on your PC. You might want to research this further and look at a database.

Comment: Just edited hope I have been more clear.

Comment: I think there is function e.layer.toGeoJson()
from that you can get the geojson and put that in an array

Comment: What about solutions in this QA: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237171/making-a-geojson-layer-editable-with-the-leaflet-editable-plugin

Comment: Yet i cant quite understand what I am supposed to do here. Should i create an empty array of the object format to be pushed in the geoJSON file, something like:

Comment: var newFeature = { 
      "type": "features", 
      "geometry": { 
        "type": layer.type,
        "coordinates": layer.getLatLngs()
      //to be continued...
      }

Comment: after that what am i supposed to do I am confused

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317249/allowing-users-to-add-data-to-marker-that-they-create-on-leaflet-map/317373#317373